# MobileFirst Platform Operational Analytics - Log Screen Visit Times and Custom Crash Details

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

I'm developing an iOS app using MFP 7.0.

Each screen (i.e., view controller) has a unique ID, and I am supposed to use Operational Analytics to send the following info to the server:

1. How long the user spent on each screen
2. On which screen the app crashed

---

Regarding #1, I guess I am supposed to use `WLAnalytics`'s

```
- (void) log:(NSString*)message withMetadata:(NSDictionary*)metadata;
```

*(right?)*

How can I manage #2? Should I just log the screen ID (using the method above) every time a transition occurs, and expect the last logged id to be passed when the crash log is sent? Or is there any other way to add custom information to crash logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Correct you can follow Custom Data, Custom Charts here https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/moving-production/operational-analytics/
2. Crash log is detected and sent automatically post crash next time app is started. There is no way to add custom data to that report. Usually the place where the error happen could be deduced form the crash data stack, if this is not sufficient, you can apply the technique you are describing.